# .htaccess rules being overriden

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently having an issue with a website I am working on. I am forwarding one URL to another URL.

In my root folder, I have the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domaina.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domainb.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It's redirecting traffic as it is supposed to, except in one directory on the website > /shop

In the /shop directory, there is also an .htaccess file and it seems to be cancelling out what I have set in the root. Here are the contents of the .htaccess in the /shop directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shop/

RewriteRule ^enclosures-enclosure-guidelines-c-229_675.html$ 
/resources#nema-guidelines [L,R=301,NE]

#RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ index.php?$cPath=$2
RewriteRule ^mc/(.*)$ mc.php?keywords=$1

RewriteRule ^(.*)-c-(.*)-p-(.*)$ product_info.php?cPath=$2&products_id=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-p-(.*)$ product_info.php?products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-c-(.*)$ index.php?cPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-c2-(.*)$ index2.php?cPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^(.*)-c-(.*)-p-(.*).html$ product_info.php?cPath=$2&products_id=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-p-(.*).html$ product_info.php?products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-c-(.*).html$ index.php?cPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-m-(.*).html$ index.php?manufacturers_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-pi-(.*).html$ popup_image.php?pID=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-t-(.*).html$ articles.php?tPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-a-(.*).html$ article_info.php?articles_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-pr-(.*).html$ product_reviews.php?products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-pri-(.*).html$ product_reviews_info.php?products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-i-(.*).html$ information.php?info_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-links-(.*).html$ links.php?lPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> it seems to be cancelling out what I have set in the root"

That's how .htaccess files work. From [the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html):

> The configuration directives found in a .htaccess file are applied to
>   the directory in which the .htaccess file is found, and to all
>   subdirectories thereof. However, it is important to also remember that
>   there may have been .htaccess files in directories higher up.
>   Directives are applied in the order that they are found. Therefore, a
>   .htaccess file in a particular directory may override directives found
>   in .htaccess files found higher up in the directory tree. And those,
>   in turn, may have overridden directives found yet higher up, or in the
>   main server configuration file itself.

Comment: So I need to move the .htaccess rules that are in the /shop directory to the root directory .htaccess file.  How can I incorporate the rewritebase rules to these so it will add /shop to all the URLs?

RewriteBase /shop/

Answer (score 0):

Inside `shop/.htaccess` you can use this directive at the top:

```
RewriteOptions InheritBefore
```

This forces the current configuration to **inherit** the configuration of the parent and applies parent rules before current .htaccess rules.

If you are on older Apache i.e. < 2.4 then use:

```
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

though remember that parent config will be applied after current set.

[Check official doc for more details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions)